# So we've got a code review tool, now what can we use for software documents?

Tags: code-reviews, review

We're using Subversion as a full CM for code and also for related project documents. We have JIRA and Fisheye. When we wanted to add a peer review tool, we looked at and tested several candidates. Our weighted requirements included both code and document review, but ultimately, the integration with JIRA slanted the scores in Crucible's favor.

Atlassian has slammed the door on ever supporting Word or PDF in Crucible. I've tested several workaround methods to make Crucible work for documents without success. (The Confluence/Crucible plug-in was deprecated by Atlassian, so that option is out, too.) I haven't found a plugin for Crucible that adds this functionality, so short of writing my own plug-in, Crucible for documents is unworkable.

Word Track Changes doesn't provide a method for true collaboration and commenting. Adobe PDF Comment and Markup is interesting, but doesn't provide a great way to keep a permanent quality record of the conversation. We can't go cloud-based, our documents must be locally hosted on our own server only. We're only on Sharepoint 2007.

Help! Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Scrap Word or PDF as a document format - instead write your code in ASCIIDoc or ReStructuredText and use that as a source to generate PDF/Word documents. The benefit of using the lightweight markup is that you can write your documents as plain old text (which programmers would like as they can do it inside the IDE, thus meaning they might do more of it) and the diffs that can be generated between documents is a solved problem. You also get the benefit of turning that into HTML or your usual format for releasing.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, at the end of the day I have had amazing luck using wiki to collaborate and store any kind of document we create including the wiki itself as documents.

Comment: We did the same, going with Trac to integrate our version control/issue management. With the Doxygen plugin to allow integration with our code documentation.